# How can I fix an exception occured in doctrine (Symfony 4)?

Tags: mysql, symfony, error-handling, doctrine

I added a column in phpmyadmin into my mySQL database. Now I wanted that my entity is also updated. So I wrote this command in the terminal:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

But I get the error message

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 98:
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE members RENAME
>   INDEX uniq_c2502824f81e0671 TO UNIQ_45A1D21   F185E0617':
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX
>   uniq_c2502824f81e0671    TO UNIQ_45A1D21FF85E0617' at line 1

This is my entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="members")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you did something wrong there.

Comment: @revengeance Yeah I know, but what

Comment: maybe post the code of your entity/entities?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber I added my entity so as you can see

Comment: Actually, what Matias said was right. In fact, you shouldn't even add a column in phpmyadmin, but simply add it to your entity (to your code) and run the command.

Comment: Where did you read in the docs you've to use phpmyadmin to add a new entity column???

Comment: @gp_sflover yeah, this was a mistake. I know now. Don't want to do this again. This caused the error, that I now need to fix ;-(

Comment: Most of your questions are answered in the documentation and you often waste more time writing it instead to read carefully the well sectioned documentation to find the answer by yourself :). PS: You already modified the DB with phpmyadmin so the fastest solution is delete the DB and reconstruct it using doctrine commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this, but you need to add your field manually to your entity. Let's suppose that you added a varchar named "token" in your table users. In your user entity, you'll need to:

```
/**
 * @ Column("token", type="string")
 */
private $token
```

With this, you are basically telling doctrine that the value you want to map to your user's object token property is in the users table and in the token field.

Make sure to clear the cache before testing this.

Comment: I have now the same fields in my database then in my entity. But still have the error described above

Comment: Can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: Where do I find stack trace exaclty?

Comment: Oh the error is now gone, I wrote only this line in terminal `composer require symfony/security-bundle` and then it worked! Strange but true

Comment: Is the part that completes the error message you posted at the beginning. Also, what action is triggering the exception exactly?